# How do you wrap a level around based on the players position

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I want to create a circular room in a 2D level. How can I handle this problem?

My thought process was to break the level into chunks and move their position depending on where the player currently is. This would allow the level to wrap around depending on where the player travels. I can do this manually with each part but i'm looking for a better solution that can handle this programatically. I'm open to better ways to solve this problem as well.

[image]
[image]

Comment: what do you mean exactly by circular? according to your linked pic , you want the player to appear from "right" if it goes beyond "left" and vice versa?

Comment: Correct. If I started at the far left side of the map and ran to the far right of the map It would wrap back around to the far left side, and vice versa. If I had a way to transition it smoothly I could probably teleport the character to each side from the edge.

Answer (score 2):

Is the space 2D? if so, you could place two invisible colliders at the extremities of the room (one at the beginning and one at the end), and change the player's position when he collides with them. To ensure that the transition is smooth, place them a little outside of the camera space: the player won't be rendered during transition, and you would obtain a teleport effect from side to side.

[image]

Comment: Yes it's 2d. I'll give this a shot.

Answer (score 1):

As another suggestion, you can lock the player to being in the center chunk with a camera just showing that chunk. Everytime he gets through a collider on the end or the start of the middle platform you delete the opposite side platform and place it in the far end of the platform the player is now seeing, effectively making the new platform as the middle one.